# Do the concepts in Java compiler apply to Android Dalvik (not ART)?

Tags: android, performance, javac, compiler-optimization, dalvik

**My questions are:**

Do the concepts in this IBM white paper [Dynamic compilation and performance measurement](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp12214/) apply to Android Dalvik (not ART)?

To be more specific, do the following concepts from that paper apply to Dalvik:

- Just-in-time compilation
- HotSpot dynamic compilation
- Continuous recompilation
- On-stack replacement
- Dynamic deoptimization

From the paper, it seems that Java code in the middle of a loop can be switched between interpretation and compilation and a compiled code can be invalidated and revert to interpretation. **Does Dalvik do that too?**

Are there any similar papers, or resources about **Dalvik compilation and performance measurement?**

I'm doing some benchmark performance measurements for my app on Dalvik and such details help me to improve my benchmark performance measurements.

Comment: The guys who wrote the JIT compiler did a Google I/O presentation back in 2010 that answers most of your questions. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ls0tM-c4Vfo

Comment: I think the video explained only the first two items in my list. Do you know any resource that could answer the other items in the list? As an update, I am writing a micro benchmark for my app not for Dalvik.